create android emulator with signed google playstore for github action
In my android application which build in flutter , integrated inApp purchase and written Integration test , and added it with github action test. Main problem is when emulator created on runnedd i am unable to signed in playStore . is there any way to create emulator runner with signed playstore .
i am using ReactiveCircus/android-emulator-runner as emulator runner on github

hen running integration tests for in-app purchases on a GitHub Action using an Android emulator, signing into the Play Store on the emulator is typically not straightforward. However, there are a few approaches you can take to potentially resolve this:
Use a pre-signed-in emulator image: One approach is to use an emulator image that already has the Play Store and a signed-in Google account. Unfortunately, GitHub Actions currently doesn't support custom images out of the box.
Script to sign in manually: Another approach involves automating the sign-in process using a script. This can be complex and may not be reliable, as it involves interacting with the Play Store sign-in UI programmatically.
Use Firebase Test Lab: Firebase Test Lab can be used to run your tests on physical devices or emulators that already have the Play Store signed in. You can integrate Firebase Test Lab with your GitHub Actions workflow.
Here's an example of how you might set up a GitHub Action workflow to use Firebase Test Lab:
Set up Firebase CLI:
Ensure you have a Firebase project and the Firebase CLI installed. You also need a service account key file for authentication.
Create a workflow file:
Here is an example GitHub Actions workflow file (.github/workflows/android.yml) that runs tests using Firebase Test

I tried Script to sign in manually but it is working in ideal senario , so it's not reliable .can you share link , how i can use Firebase testlab emulator

@ManishSharma this answer is just a copy-paste from ChatGPT - there's nothing useful to learn from the author.
